# How to add multiple CDN files into bundle

Tags: c#, asp.net, bundle

Found this snippet to add cdn file into bundle:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    //bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
    //            "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

    bundles.UseCdn = true;   //enable CDN support

    //add link to jquery on the CDN
    var jqueryCdnPath = "https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js";

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery",
                jqueryCdnPath).Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));    
}
```

But is there any way to add multiple cdn files into that bundle? We have locally hosted cdn if that makes a difference, so the url for jqueryCdnPath would start with https://localhost... most likely (comes from config).

Include() supports array of string (but my understanding is these are local files only used when Debuggin), but for cdn part (used in release mode) I cannot see this to be the case??

Found this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20691979/visual-studio-js-bundling-multiple-cdn-files), there is no answer and it is from 2013 so thought maybe something has changed since then..

Many Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add many CDN bundles in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48129653/add-many-cdn-bundles-in-mvc)

Comment: @Muhammad Asad  - No, unfortunately it does not. I want to add multiple files that are external to the solution (coming from locally hosted cdn) into the bundle.